# Cascading dropdown controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following C# Code that works, so when I select the Country dropdown, the state dropdown is populated.

What I am trying to do if the State dropdown (comboBox2) is selected, the respective country(comboBox1) selectedIndex should be changed to the respective country.

Example: when Gujrat is selected it should show India in the first comboBox1

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  

using System.Data.SqlClient;  

namespace cascadingdropdownlist  
{  
    public partial class Form1 : Form  
    {  
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");  
        DataRow dr;  

        public Form1()  
        {  
            InitializeComponent();  
            refreshdata();  
        }  

        public void refreshdata()  
        {  
            con.Open();  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_country", con);  
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);  
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
            sda.Fill(dt);  
            con.Close();  
            dr = dt.NewRow();  
            dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "--Select Country--" };  
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);  
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "countryid";  
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "countryname";  
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        }  

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
            if (comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()!= null)  
            {  
                int countryid = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());  
                refreshstate(countryid);   
            }  
        }  

        public void refreshstate(int countryid)  
        { 
            con.Open();  
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_state where countryid= @countryid", con);  
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("countryid", countryid);  
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);  
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
            sda.Fill(dt);  
            con.Close();  
            dr = dt.NewRow();  
            dr.ItemArray = new object[] { 0, "--Select State--" };  
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);  

            comboBox2.ValueMember = "stateid";  
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "statename";  
            comboBox2.DataSource = dt;  
        }
    }
}
```

Screens
[image][image][image]

Comment: Without country, states won't get populated according to your code? Then how can you select state, for a country other than selected ?

Comment: @Krishna By default both dropdowns when the form loads should show all states and all countries

Comment: I don't see it in the form load, I see only country data loading, anyway what's the problem you are facing ?

Comment: it doesn't make sense to me - you can't change state and select another country. This is one way road. Select country --> populate states

Answer (score 0):

There will be two way cascading objects. Considering you have loaded comboboxes at the beginning, you should handle the combobox2 selection change event. Instead of dealing with value, you can just cast the SelectedValue to appropriate object as below so that you can extract the countryid value. Then, you should just set the selectedValue of the combobox1. You should note that there will be a vicious circle if you do not prevent execution of comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged. Thus, I used **doNotCascade = true;** to emphasis this issue, and you should check this variable in the comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

Hope helps.

```
private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView item = comboBox2.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
    if (item != null && this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        doNotCascade = true;
        this.comboBox1.SelectedValue = item.Row[2];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to write a `sub query` for this:

```
create proc sp_FindCountryName 
@stateName varchar(40)
as
begin 
  select countryName from country where countryID=(
  select countryID from [State] where stateName=@stateName)
end
```

then implement the `comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged` method (here `cbState` is the second `comboBox`)

```
private void cbState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (cbState.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
     {
         string stateName = this.cbState.GetItemText(this.cbState.SelectedItem);
         retriveCountryName(stateName);
     }

}

private void retriveCountryName(string stateName)
{
    using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
         con.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_FindCountryName", con);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stateName", stateName);
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         da.Fill(dt);
         dr = dt.NewRow();
         cbCountry.ValueMember = "countryID";
         cbCountry.DisplayMember = "countryName";
         cbCountry.DataSource = dt;

    }
}
```